# Excel VBA Not Generating E-Mail If One File Is Missing From a List of Attachments

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA set up to loop through an Excel document to generate emails that could have anywhere from 1 to 10 possible attachments. Week to week the files existing could change. After the company upgraded our Excel, instead of still generating an email with all available files, if one is missing now it will not generate an email at all with the remaining available files. I have tried to remove "on error resume next" and removed the pop up msg box but neither helped.  No special error message/debugging pops up, it just pops up the Yes/No box without generating any email.

```
Option Explicit
Sub SendEmailsWeeklys()
 Dim olApp As Object
   Dim olMailItm As Object
    Dim cell As Range, D As Range
    Dim Subj As String
    Dim EmailAddr As String
    Dim Recipient As String
    Dim Msg As String, SigString As String, Signature As String
    Dim WkEnd As String, send As Integer, dCount As Long, dTest As Long

If ActiveSheet.Name = "Weekly Distribution" Then
WkEnd = DateAdd("d", -2, Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy"))

Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    
    'Loop through the rows
    For Each cell In Range(Range("B2"), Range("B999999").End(xlUp))
    EmailAddr = cell.Value
    Msg = "Hello," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
    "Attached is the QA Report for the week ending " & WkEnd & "." & vbNewLine & _
    "If you have questions regarding the content of this report, please contact" & " " & 
     Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 1).Value & "." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
    "Thanks," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
    
   Subj = "QA Report: " & Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, -1).Value & " - Week Ending " & WkEnd

Set olMailItm = olApp.CreateItem(0)
With olMailItm
.To = EmailAddr
.Subject = Subj
.Body = Msg
.Recipients.ResolveAll


On Error Resume Next

For Each D In Range(Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 2), Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 
9999).End(xlToLeft))
.attachments.Add "C:\Users\" & (Environ$("Username")) & "\Desktop\Process Production\" & 
D.Value & ".xlsx"
Next D
If .attachments.Count = 0 Then
MsgBox (Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, -1).Value & " - No Attachments Present")
Else
.display
Dim RS As Integer
RS = MsgBox("Send?", vbYesNo, "Continue")
If RS = vbYes Then
.send
ElseIf RS = vbNo Then
Debug.Print Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, -1).Value
End If
End If


End Sub
```

The excel sheet it references is set up like this(there are way more columns/rows but for the sake of keeping this smaller):

|Email Subject | Email Addresses| Dept | File 1| File 2|

So if file 1 is missing, but file 2 exists, this current code will not generate an email at all and I still need it to write the email with just file 2 attached.

Thank you for any guidance.

Comment: You can check if a file exists before trying to add it to the attachments. `If Len(Dir(path)) > 0 Then [...]`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I put it up above the On Error Resume Next section and got many compile errors about no Next without a For . I made sure all my Fors had the correct amount of Next and all If statements had end if but it seems to cycle between not even Next or not enough End If.  Should this actually go up near the top?  Sorry I have never used IF LEN before and was just trying it out in that area. I wrote it out like this  

 If Len(Dir("C:\Users\" & (Environ$("Username")) & "\Desktop\Process Production\")) & D.Value & ".xlsx" > 0 Then

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to check, if a file exists at all.

One possibility is:

```
...
Dim ChkFile As String, CurFile As String

For Each D In Range(Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 2), Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 9999).End(xlToLeft))
   ChkFile = "C:\Users\" & (Environ$("Username")) & "\Desktop\Process Production\" & D.Value & ".xlsx"
   CurFile = Dir(ChkFile)
   If CurFile <> "" Then .attachments.Add ChkFile
Next D
...
```